# Which framework for multi-tenant SaaS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, grails, spring-mvc, frameworks, saas

I am looking to build a multi-tenant SaaS app for creating and managing domain-specific content (sorta like a CMS but very domain specific). This app will support some basic workflow (change approval process) and possible (down the road, not now) integration with legacy enterprise identity management solutions (LDAP or A/D).

I come from a Java/J2EE background (I'm former Oracle/BEA), however I've been recently turned on to RoR, as well as Grails. Haven't done anything with Spring, but that's an option as well.

Regardless, given the very high-level description of what I'm trying to achieve, which frameworks would best meet my needs (for the least amount of pain!) ? I know Java, I could certainly do this with a pure java framework, however I really like the convention or configuration aspect I'm seeing with RoR. I just don't know if RoR can meet my potential enterprise integration needs. My experience with RoR is very limited - I'm just learning about it now. Most of my development knowledge is tied up in Java. I have no problems switching gears and learning another language.

with that said, I've read quite a few Q/As on here regarding grails vs RoR vs Java (Spring, JSF, etc..) and my head is spinning.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a strict deadline i would say go for something you already know, you'll be faster so Java for the language.
In terms of framework if it is a web based multi-tenant CMS like you describe, i would check GWT, Play, Grails because they are made for Web and have some usefull tools built-in.

If you have more time and can afford to learn a new language / framework, then go for RoR, you'll have a learning curve but it seems a good choice particulary for web project and you would be able to get a prototype quickly.
For the entreprise integration part, if it is only interfacing with Ldap / AD there is tools for that in rails like [net-ldap](http://net-ldap.rubyforge.org/)
If your need more, you could also think of JRuby which would allow you to code in RoR but deploy on JVM and possibly use Java library

Answer (score 0):

With you being familiar with Java, you might enjoy Grails: it's programmed in Groovy, which is a dynamic dialect of Java (most Java code is legal Groovy code), so you should find the language easy to pick up. You'll still have access to familiar libraries and frameworks from the Java world, and Grails itself is modelled after RoR. A Grails deploy is usually just a .war file, so you can use a familiar Java web container, like JBoss, Tomcat or Jetty.